# How to extend Django User model with two different profiles?

Tags: python, django, models

Is it possible to create two different profiles and have them both extend Django User Model. I am trying to create a student profile and a teacher profile, how should I go about doing this? My student profile has attributes such as courses taken, but the teacher should not have access to taking courses, only create them.

Answer (score 3):

You can create multiple models inherit `User` model.

```
class Teacher(User):
    pass

class Course(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)

class Student(User):
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit the django builtin `User` Models class into any number of models.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models User

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(-----)

class Teacher(User):
    pass

class Course(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)

class Student(User):
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
```